# replace a substring from a hyperlink c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

Using c#.net 4.0
wondering how to replace a dynamic substring from a long string(url w/ parameters). Basically i have a row of hyperlinks when clicked should navigate to a url but part of the link should be cut off from it.

display Url

http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/service/demoportal/thirdpartyaccess.htm?wwpage=**http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/services/gtame/summary.htm**&token=e250656e73b3a058d6931d045c85b8e722be892ebec69fa4fa56aa19bbce5f53

navigate the above to below once the above url is clicked

Navigate URL

http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/service/demoportal/thirdpartyaccess.htm?wwpage=**services/gtame/summary.htm**&token=e250656e73b3a058d6931d045c85b8e722be892ebec69fa4fa56aa19bbce5f53

Thanks

Comment: does the position of substring to be cut remains same or changes???...u should look in to linkbutton..that will help...

Comment: @CodeJack from http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/ is dynamic but we can fix the start point "wwpage=" and end point "/services" and cut the in between, just wondering is it possible to get index of starting & ending point of word eg "wwpage="  after "=" and before "/services"?

Comment: so string to be reduced can be from any position?????

Comment: @CodeJack yes anywhere in between "wwpage=" and "/services"

Comment: Is my solution not enough yet? What else do you need?

Comment: thn BlueM's answer will work for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string s = "http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/service/demoportal/thirdpartyaccess.htm?wwpage=http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/services/gtame/summary.htm&token=e250656e73b3a058d6931d045c85b8e722be892ebec69fa4fa56aa19bbce5f53";
  s = Regex.Replace(s, "(.*wwpage\\=).*/(services.*)", "$1$2");
```

output:

```
http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/service/demoportal/thirdpartyaccess.htm?wwpage=services/gtame/summary.htm&token=e250656e73b3a058d6931d045c85b8e722be892ebec69fa4fa56aa19bbce5f53
```

Comment: the following is dynamic http://10.2.2.13:6060/demo/ and cud be something else as well for each row.

Comment: Ok I changed my regex to do cut everything inbetween.

Comment: thanks a ton! i was lost in outspace trying to use indexof and substring. Also just wondering what the new select<> does is that of any use for above problem